# Can I run the nohup command from tcsh

Tags: bash, command-line, rhel, tcsh, nohup

I am looking into the nohup command and I am not sure which shells it support. It seems as if this program works differently in bash and tcsh. What I tried was something very simple.

```
nohup --help
```

When I start it from bash it works just fine, but for tcsh is says,

> --help: Command not found.

This does definitely not mean the command not works, but this is a confusing indicator. Due to that the settings on the machine I run on seems to keep programs a fairly long time before they terminate, it is hard to actually verify that nohup is working.

Another indicator that things no works as expected is that when running the script I plan to run it does also work differently. When running in bash it will output to nohup.out, while in tcsh it does not (it outputs to the terminal I run the nohup command in).

Any ideas?

Tested on both rhel6 and rhel7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in `bash`, using `nohup` will use the external utility `nohup`.  The GNU coreutils' version of `nohup` does indeed have a `--help` flag that will output some information.

When in `tcsh`, using `nohup` will use the shell's built-in command `nohup`, even in an external utility of the same name exists. See the `tcsh` manual for more information about the built-in `nohup` in that shell.

To use GNU coreutils' `nohup` in `tcsh`, use the utility with its full path, e.g., `/usr/bin/nohup --help`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I just found the nohup built-in command in the tcsh man page. Seems I missed on the overloading. Unfortunately the man page does not lead to the built-in command :(

Comment: @patrik No, built-in utilities doesn't usually have their own manuals but are usually documented in the shell's own manual (except for in `zsh` where the builtins have their own dedicated text in the separate `zshbuiltins` manual).